# Change title of a Navigation Bar dragged in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I would like to change font and color of the title of a Navigation Bar i dragged in the storyboards from the palette (not auto-created with a nag controller + push segue).
i already tried

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.title = @"title";
self.title = @"title";
self.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```

but none of them works. No title is displayed, so i didn't even tried any change of fonts or colors.
How can i fix?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the navigation bar is a part of some navigationController.

Try this :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarColor"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

self.title = @"Title here!";
```

Or else :

```
 UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 170.0f, 44.0f)];

    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.textColor       = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.922f green: 0.925f blue: 0.973f alpha: 1.0f];
    titleLabel.font            = [Utils helveticaBoldFontOfSize: 19.333f];
    titleLabel.text            = NSLocalizedString(@"Title Here", nil);
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Comment: it's not gonna work;( the view controller is not directly embedded in a navig controller, but i come to this view with a modal segue from a view with nav controller, may this be the problem?